# Remote Work for US-Based Candidates

Tags: telecommute, remote-work

What does it mean if a remote job description says that the candidate must be US-based ?

I am a US citizen and maintain a bank account in the US. Given this, if the company pays me in US dollars in my US account but I am not physically present in the US, does that make me US-based?

One operating assumption here is that the job is such that it never requires commute to the office. Thanks!!

Comment: Also, while it may rea, "US-based," you might also need to be in certain US States.

Comment: US-based means "subject ONLY to US taxes and US labor laws". It has nothing to do with your citizenship but your place of residence and  what tax laws the company must comply with to pay you.

Comment: Remote work can even be restrict to certain states in US, so that they do not have to worry about complying with 50 from slightly to very different sets of state labor laws.

Answer (score 7):

> What does it mean if a remote work job description says that the
> candidate must be US-based.

It means you must live somewhere within the US.

Usually, this is for tax reasons. US companies can have a tax nexus in a US state far more easily than outside the US.

> if the company pays me in US dollars in my US account but I am not physically present in the US, does that make me US-based?

No, it does not.

Answer (score 4):

US based means that is your main place of residence or that you're in the US. Having a bank account there and being a citizen isn't the same.

But having said that, you could still apply for the positions and explain that when necessary.

Comment: Usually this requirement is because payment and taxes across international boundaries is a LOT of hassle unless the company has an office in the country and can pay you from there. Unless you're an exceptional candidate, they are going to be inclined to hire someone who is less trouble to them.